# Error en Constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

A ver si me pueden ayudar tengo el siguiente error y no se como solucionarlo

```
    public SeedDb(DataContext context, IUserHelper userHelper)
    {
        _dataContext = context;
        _userHelper = userHelper;
    }
```

En el `SeedDb` me lo marca en rojo y el error es:

> Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'IUserHelper' is less
>   accessible than method 'SeedDb.SeedDb(DataContext, IUserHelper)'

No se porqué me está pasando eso

Comment: hace publica la interface IUserHelper, ahora la debes tener como privada

Comment: como declaras la IUserHelper ?

Answer (score 0):

Tu error puede reproducirse con [este código](https://tio.run/##TU/NasMwDD7bT6H15ECXFyg7dYwWNih0pYUxiuuIYHCtIDlZS8mzZ@4f5CKQvl85eXXihqEVH2tYnyXhcaa1C1YE5nmivmjVtIfgHXTkK/hoo/MUzbdvaMW@sxVBZwNxoVWmqv1tgbf7caZVr7PBlZgQ7r4j6WWMji33D3n/LLNiqtkeIWdIsulZ58v6aCRxrv/zC5ZrefTYwSmHq1O5RqzeDybiH@zK5UaQFxgaZFMUV8KcolDAcss@4aePaCYZDzSFLXGoXibF7Yd@GP4B):

```
class Clase
{
    public void Funcion(TipoPrivado valor)
    {
        _valor = valor;
    }

    private class TipoPrivado{}

    private TipoPrivado _valor;
}
```

¿Cómo podemos llamar a la función pública `Funcion` pasando un argumento de tipo `TipoPrivado` si dicho tipo es inaccesible porque es `private`?:

```
Clase c = new Clase();
c.Funcion(new Clase.TipoPrivado());
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- ¡Esto es privado!
```

Si haces que el tipo interno sea accesible desde fuera, el error desaparece:

```
class Clase
{
    public void Funcion(TipoPrivado valor)
    {
        _valor = valor;
    }

    // Ahora 'TipoPrivado' no es privado si no público, ¡error resuelto!
    public class TipoPrivado{}

    private TipoPrivado _valor;
}
```